# left and right arrows not appearning in carousel in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class=" pull-left carousel slide" style="width: 950px; padding-right: -100px; margin: 0 auto" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/lab4.jpg" alt="Chania" width="500" height="375">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Lab building</h3>
        <p> Entrance for great future</p>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/lab5.jpg" alt="Chania" width="500" height="375">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Lotus</h3>
        <p> Beauty of nature</p>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/lab6.jpg" alt="Flower" width="500" height="375">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Resource Centre</h3>
        <p> A Temple of Books</p>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

I am trying to implement a carousel using bootstrap,but i am unable to see to see the arrows for navigation instead i see this character "%o". in the console i get the following error::

```
GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 (anonymous function) @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3605jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3144jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3256jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3468completed @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3499
home:1 GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
home:1 GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

I searched the error and found a comment in github as::

```
Make sure you're including the Glyphicon font files - carousel arrows are using Glyphicon chevrons by default.
```

how do i include Glyphicon font files??
thanks in advance
i chnaged my bootstrap.css at @font-face:::

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

but still i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ttf file `glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf` for the glyphicons font, you'll find it in the bootstrap distribution zip file, just add the missing file to `fonts/` and it should work.

Also, verify that you have included correctly in the `<head>` of your page the bootstrap css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<your_css_directory>/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: thanks @uraimo
i have linked bootstrap.min.css file to my rails application
and  i have placed the fonts folder (from bootstrap distribution zip file) in /app/assets folder
but still i am unable to see the arrows

Comment: Oh ok, was about to reply to add a "../" :D

Answer (score -1):

i tried to change my bootstrap.css @font-face part to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

and it worked